# Implementing Room SQLIte in new Thread

Tags: sqlite, android-room

What is the best practise for getting data from Room SQLite from a new thread to main UI thread in android?

Comment: The 2 most common ways : 1. Use LiveData as return type for dao queries. Room will automatically take care the background thread loading. 2. Put the dao query in an AsyncTask. Not sure if that's what you are asking so I leave it as a comment.

Comment: Could we call a method in UI thread from inside AysncTask as callback after data retrieval?

Comment: Of course. onPostExecute is called after the AsyncTask finished and is called on UI thread.

Comment: thanks. made by day. if you want +1, post it as answer. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little reminder : This AsyncTask solution is just for quick implementation for a few queries. If you have lots of different queries, don't try to create a bunch of AsyncTask subclasses to handle. Better look at the LiveData way or manage a thread yourself.

---

Assuming you are querying for list of all users :

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {
    @Query("Select * FROM User")
    List<User> findAll();
}
```

Sample async task

```
private static class UserTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<User>> {
    UserDao dao;

    public UserTask(UserDao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<User> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        // this function runs in a background thread managed by system
        return dao.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<User> users) {
        // This runs in UI thread after doInBackground return. Run your ui callback here
        super.onPostExecute(users);
    }
}
```

Comment: You mention don't use AsyncTask if there are a lot of queries.  What if there is one query but the List is very large?  Is it then more appropriate to use LiveData rather than loading all of the Users with AsyncTask?

Comment: If the query is very large and you are trying to display a list then it is best if you paginate it, Room has integration with the AndroidX Pagination library, might be worth checking it out.